# UserName when signing up

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, username

Why is it that when you sign up for this site you do not put in your username only when you sign up and it becomes UserXXXXX can you go on your profile and change it.

I feel like it would be eaiser to put in the signing up What is your Username (public).

Comment: [If you ask a question when not logged in, you get a few options.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W4lSW.png) Of those, "Post as a guest" & "Sign up using Stack Exchange" *do* prompt you for a "Name". Only "Sign up using Google/Facebook" and "log in" using Google/Facebook don't. It's to the latter group that your question applies.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186121/166155

Comment: Me personally when I signed up. Which I did through the sign up bottom on the top right corner. And I clicked sign up through StackExchange and I did not have to put a username

Comment: @user6781, you didn't have to put one, but didn't it prompt you for one?